# Access denied with correct password with mobaxterm on one machine. It works on another work station

Tags: networking, server, ssh, password

I am new to the ubuntu system, and I did follow the instruction to use Mobaxterm to connect with my two workstations. Both workstation with right SSH could connect with my Mobaxterm, but one with right username and password, my access is denied. However, I could log in on the workstation with same username and password. Another workstation works fine with right username and password. Please help!

Thanks
Alex